# RFT: How can I export error messages generated on screen during playback

Tags: java, export, automated-tests, export-to-csv, rft

I'm writing a negative test script in order to deliberately generate error messages which will be displayed on the screen to the end user. I've written the script and it works, and I added a System.print in order to write the message to the console.

My question is how do I write this message to a txt file instead? I'd like to have the error message automatically added to a text file after each run.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RFT does not provide any APIs to write to file as such. You will need to use  Java  to get things done.

Following link should help 
[how to create a file-stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file)